# Need Help in drawing buttons around the circular path in Java code?

Tags: android

i can get a central point of the circular,so i want to draw some buttons  around the central point of the circular,as you seen in this image http://i.6.cn/cvbnm/50/97/b0/e7ed11251c3069fea4130c74b3ecb10c.png  ,can you give me some advice,Links to examples will be more useful. This is My code

Edit:

```
public class drawCirPicture extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new SampleView(this));
}

private static class SampleView extends View {
    private Bitmap mBitmap;




    public SampleView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setFocusable(true);

        InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(android.R.drawable.sym_call_outgoing);
        mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

    }

    @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.GRAY);

        Paint p = new Paint();
        float centerY = 200;
        float centerX=130;

       double alpha = 0,wedge=0;
       double PI=Math.PI;

        float x,y;

        int radius=55;

        for (alpha = 0, wedge = 2 * PI / 4; alpha < 2 * PI; alpha += wedge)
        {
            x = (float) (centerX + radius * Math.cos(alpha));
            y = (float) (centerY + radius * Math.sin(alpha));
            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, x, y, p);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean performClick() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.performClick();
    }
    }
}
```

i am able to  put images in the circular path, but i was not able to implement ontouch event or onclick event of every image, and also the centerX or centerY  locate the edge of the screen ,how to put the images to the wide area of the screen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
x = centerX + radius * cos(alpha)
y = centerY + radius * sin(alpha)
```

Where `alpha` is between 0 and `2 * PI`.

Trigonometry is cool.

Comment: i cannot understand,i want to draw more buttons,can you give more details,how to draw buttons to the canvas

Comment: As I said, this is not Android question, it's maths question. Say you need N buttons. Do `for (alpha = 0, wedge = 2 * PI / N; alpha < 2 * PI; alpha += wedge)`, and calculate the coordinates according to the formulae in my answer. Then just draw the buttons normally at those positions. You might need to adjust to center the buttons at the coordinate (as opposed to setting top and left corner to those x and y)

Comment: thank you for your answer,i know your method can draw buttons,but how to  create / draw the circular buttons to put in android view? how to use the click of the buttons? can you understand my question?

Comment: i think you method have some fault,for example if the  centerX=10,centery=50,it can cut my pic,can you give me more clue .thank you

Comment: can you tell me how to around circular arc,instead of the whole circular,i think the method more good.your method put all buttons around the whole circular.

Comment: `2 * PI` is the whole circle; reduce for a smaller arc.

Answer (score 1):

thank you @Amadan, you give me a clue, when i want to put imageViews or buttons to the view,i found very hard,so at last i used the  AbsoluteLayout:

```
public class drawCirPicture extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   // setContentView(new SampleView(this));
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    AbsoluteLayout ab =(AbsoluteLayout) findViewById(R.id.a1);

    float centerY = 200;
    float centerX=130;

   double alpha = 0,wedge=0;
   double PI=Math.PI;

    float x,y;

    int radius=55;


    InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.ic_jog_dial_unlock);
    Bitmap  mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

    for (alpha = 0, wedge = 2 * PI / 5; alpha < 2 * PI; alpha += wedge)
    {
        x = (float) (centerX + radius * Math.cos(alpha));
        y = (float) (centerY + radius * Math.sin(alpha));
        //canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, x, y, p);
        ImageView iv =new ImageView(this);
        iv.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
        iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(drawCirPicture.this, "a", 1000).show();
            }
        });
        ab.addView(iv,new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(mBitmap.getWidth(), mBitmap.getHeight(),(int) x,(int) y));
    }


}
```

it can solve my question,the fault is at present i cannot deal with the boundary,for example when centerX= 5 ,centery=10,the effect not my need,i need to further work ,i want you  can give more clue ,thank you