# Circular Images - Android

Tags: android, imageview

Given a number by the user, between 4 and 16, I am required to display a number of small images in a circle.  If the user selects 4, then I need 4 small images in a circle, and if the user selects 12, I need 12 images forming the circle and so on.

It is not so much the calculation of the coordinates of the image but actually just how I would go about setting this up?

Do I use a single Imageview? Multiple Imageviews?

Comment: x = r * cos(angle), y = r * sin(angle) ?

Comment: hey look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453949/need-help-in-drawing-buttons-around-the-circular-path-in-java-code?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: it has the formula and the number 6 can be changed to 4 or 16 accordingly. Also you can  change the radius as per your choice.

Comment: I don't think ImageView(s) will be a good solution since you need to position the images by yourself. I would consider using a canvas and draw the images by yourself.

Comment: Have You tried to create simple custom ViewGroup which could handle proper positioning of any number of ImageView in a circle?